# SSRS 2008 Values on X and Y axis

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report in ms excel that needs to be converted to SSRS report. 
the data below was used from CHECKIN_TBL

```
CheckINDate CheckInTime MinsWaitKid  MinsWaitAdult
17/10/2016  00:54:21    3261    1620
19/10/2016  00:52:32    3152    1617
21/10/2016  00:52:08    3128    1564
24/10/2016  00:51:45    3105    1591
20/10/2016  00:50:56    3056    1548
13/10/2016  00:50:47    3047    1565
15/10/2016  00:50:31    3031    1615
18/10/2016  00:48:17    2897    1455
23/10/2016  00:43:30    2610    1636
14/10/2016  00:43:14    2594    1560
26/10/2016  00:38:17    2297    1602
25/10/2016  00:32:48    1968    1327
16/10/2016  00:30:09    1809    1598
22/10/2016  00:18:57    1137    1635
```

I am having difficulties in display the time and date in both a and y axis respectively. any help guys.  thanks

See image below 
[image]

Comment: What message do you want the chart to convey to the end-user?

Comment: @DatumPoint 23 I want to compare adult waiting time with children waiting time in line graph. Thanks